# レイアウトを動的に追加したい｡

Tags: android, android-layout

レイアウトを動的に追加するコードを書いたのですが､うまく行かず表示されません｡
以下の`three_grid_row.xml`に`grid_item.xml`を3つ水平に並べたものを複数作成し､ルートビューである`fragment_video_info.xml`のLinearLayoutである`suggestion_video_list`に追加します｡
実行してみるとエラーは出ないのですが`suggest_video_list`が表示されません｡

**`fragment_video_info.xml`の一部:**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/suggestion_video_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
 </LinearLayout>
```

**`three_grid_row.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

**`grid_item.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/suggest_duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/suggest_video_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/suggest_ch_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/suggest_video_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/suggest_video_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/suggest_ch_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**処理部:**

```
if (!relatedVideoList.isEmpty()) {
            //layoutInflaterを取得
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //LinearLayoutを入れる配列を作る
            LinearLayout[] gridRowList = new LinearLayout[7];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                gridRowList[i] = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.three_grid_row, null);
            }
            for (int i = 3; i < 7; i++) {
                gridRowList[i] = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.three_grid_row, null);
                gridRowList[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            //LinearLayoutに追加
            int count = 0;
            for (VideoItems item : relatedVideoList) {
                FrameLayout gridItem = null;
                if (count < 3) {
                    gridItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, gridRowList[0], false);
                } else if (count >= 3 && count < 6) {
                    gridItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, gridRowList[1], false);
                } else if (count >= 6 && count < 9) {
                    gridItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, gridRowList[2], false);
                } else if (count >= 9 && count < 12) {
                    gridItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, gridRowList[3], false);
                } else if (count >= 12 && count < 15) {
                    gridItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, gridRowList[4], false);
                } else if (count >= 15 && count < 18) {
                    gridItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, gridRowList[5], false);
                } else if (count >= 18 && count < 21) {
                    gridItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, gridRowList[6], false);
                }

                //Viewをセット
                if (gridItem != null) {
                    SuggestViewHolder holder = new SuggestViewHolder();
                    setGridItemView(gridItem, holder);
                    setGridItemContents(holder, item);
                }
                count++;
            }

            //LinearLayoutにViewをセット
            LinearLayout suggestVideoContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_video_list);
            for (LinearLayout item : gridRowList) {
                suggestVideoContainer.addView(item);
            }

            //関連動画を出すボタンの有無をセットする
            if (gridRowList.length < 4 ) {
                LinearLayout suggestButton = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.suggest_exp_button);
                suggestButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

**`setGridItemView`:**

```
 private void setGridItemView(FrameLayout gridItem, SuggestViewHolder holder){
    holder.suggestThumbnail = (ImageView)gridItem.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail);
    holder.suggestDuration = (TextView)gridItem.findViewById(R.id.suggest_duration);
    holder.suggestVideoName = (TextView)gridItem.findViewById(R.id.suggest_video_name);
    holder.suggestChannelName = (TextView)gridItem.findViewById(R.id.suggest_ch_name);
    holder.suggestViewCount = (TextView)gridItem.findViewById(R.id.suggest_video_view);
}
```

**`setGridItemContents`:**

```
private void setGridItemContents(SuggestViewHolder holder, VideoItems videoItems){
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(videoItems.snippet.thumbnails.default1.url).into(holder.suggestThumbnail);
    holder.suggestChannelName.setText(videoItems.snippet.channelTitle);
    holder.suggestDuration.setText(durationConverter(videoItems.contentDetails.duration));
    holder.suggestVideoName.setText(videoItems.snippet.title);
    holder.suggestViewCount.setText(numberConverter(videoItems.statistics.viewCount, 0) + " " + getString(R.string.views));
}
```

なにか､間違えているところがありましたら教えて下さい｡よろしくお願いします｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gridItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null); 
gridRowList[0].addView(gridItem);
```

こんな感じの処理にしてもダメですか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます｡
これで表示はできたのですが､親の`LinearLayout`から子の`FrameLayout`がはみ出してしまいました｡

Answer (score 2):

この手のレイアウトがうまくいかないときの調べ方のコツを書いておきます。

いくつかあるのですが、まずはいろいろな View/ViewGroup に対して 
android:background="#f00" の様な感じで色をつけていって、 
今見えているのがどの View になっているのかを確認していくのがお手軽です。
ハマった時はこの方法で、意図どおりのレイアウトになっているかを一歩ずつ
確認していくといいです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます｡ 参考にさせていただきます｡

Answer (score 1):

LayoutInflater#inflate()に第2引数を指定、第3引数をtrueにする。

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  inflater.inflate(R.layout.foo, parent, true);
  // 追加したViewを取得
  View view = parent.getChildView(i);
}
```

## 追記

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.suggestion_video_list);
fot (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
  inflater.inflate(R.layout.three_grid_row, container, true);
  ViewGroup rowContainer = (ViewGroup) relatedVideoList.getChildAt(i);
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, rowContainer, true);
    ViewGroup gridItemView = (ViewGroup) rowContainer.getChildAt(j);

    ImageView thumb = (ImageView) gridItemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail);
    // do something
    TextView duration = (TextView) gridItemView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_duration);
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: 回答有難うございます｡  回答を見させて頂いて､inflateの第三引数をtrueにするのはわかったのですが､これをどこで実装すればいいのかがわかりません｡  もう少し詳しく教えていただけますでしょうか｡

Comment: 追記:
以下のように変えて見たのですがエラーが出てしまいました｡
`gridItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, gridRowList[0], true);`

エラー:
 `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout`

Comment: 追記ありがとう御座います｡  すみません｡ わかりづらかったかもしれませんが､`relatedVideoList`はViewではなく､各コンポーネントに表示する情報が入っている`VideoItems`というオブジェクトのリストです｡  なので､`inflater`の引数に入れるこができないと思おうのですが｡

Answer (score 1):

gridItemというビューをどこにも追加していないので、表示されていません。

```
gridRowList[番号].addView(gridItem);
```

というコードを入れることで表示されるようになると思います。

---

inflateメソッドが追加していると思っているのかもしれませんが、最後の引数がfalseだと追加されません。
trueであれば追加されますが、2つ目の引数がnullでなければそれを返すようになるので、その場合生成されたビューをgetChildAtなど別の方法を使って取得する必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

viewの宣言位置の記述がないので何とも言えませんがinvalidate()で再描画したらどうでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます｡  `view.invalidate()`を実行しましたが､直りませんでした｡